# unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new'

Tags: steam, dpkg, debian-stretch

I've been trying to install steam on debian 9, I need to get the i386 architecture, but it doesn't let me do it

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

returns 
`amd64`

and when i use `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` 
       it returns with `i386`

using `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` 
returns me nothing but it also doesnt update even after

```
sudo apt-get update
```

without using sudo I get the following error

```
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
```

I can't seem to find a fix regarding my system

Comment: What question *is* you asking?

Comment: why cant i add that architecture to my OS, ive done every guide to do that, but they plainly do not work

Comment: Isn't that `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` indicated that you have already added the architecture i386 into your OS?

Comment: but steam wont launch because the library isnt installed, it says "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1" and my package managers and apt-get say that package doesnt exist, my source list already has non-free and contrib inside so that shouldnt be the issue

Comment: So your real question became how to install libGL.so.1:i386 into your Linux, not how to add the target architecture.

Comment: if it gets me to use steam, yes :D

Comment: Then I tried `dpkg -S libGL.so.1 | grep i386`, and found the package libgl1:i386, which means `sudo apt-get install libgl1:i386` may solve your _current_ real problem.

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' instead of 'libgl1:i386'
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is already the newest version (13.0.6-1+b2).
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 set to manually installed.`

Comment: it might be on the wrong folder? because its still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *install* the Steam for Windows snap run `snap install steamforwindows --edge`

If you trying to *build* the Steam for Windows snap run:

```
git clone https://github.com/snapcrafters/steamforwindows.git
cd steamforwindows
sudo snapcraft # needs sudo to enable the i386 architecture
```